# ios RestKit post attached UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to post an image to my server using RestKit and map response from server. But server always back that file I am sending is nil.
Could anyone help me with that issue?

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageData, 1.0);



NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        data, @"avatar",
                        nil];


RKObjectMapping* objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UpdateAvatar class]];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"message" : @"message"
                                                    }];

NSIndexSet *successStatusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:successStatusCodes];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[self defineBaseUrl]];
[[objectManager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"device_uid" value:[self getDeviceUid]];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"multipart/form-data"];
[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[objectManager postObject:nil path:@"/api/upload-avatar" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"%@", mappingResult.array);

    for (UpdateAvatar *obj in mappingResult.array) {

        NSLog(@"MESSAGE: %@", obj.message);

        [[DataManager sharedManager] setMessage:obj.message];

    }

    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Profile Picture Updated"];
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didRegistered" object:nil];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Comment: How is the server expecting to receive the image data exactly?

Comment: @Wain Thanks :) solved it. posted my answer below :)

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my issue with Documentation from RESTKit itself.
Maybe it will help to someone else:

```
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageData, 0.3);

RKObjectMapping* objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UpdateAvatar class]];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"message" : @"message"
                                                    }];

NSIndexSet *successStatusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:successStatusCodes];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[DataManager defineBaseUrl]];
[[objectManager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"device_uid" value:[self getDeviceUid]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/api/upload-avatar" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data
                                name:@"avatar"
                            fileName:@"image.jpeg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    for (UpdateAvatar *obj in mappingResult.array) {

        [SVProgressHUD setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.31 green:0.31 blue:0.31 alpha:0.5]];
        [SVProgressHUD setRingThickness:2];
        [SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploading avatar\n %@", obj.message]];
    }


} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```